# Printing information about a specific user from /etc/passwd

Tags: grep, passwd

So I'm trying to list a bunch of info about users in etc/passwd. So far I managed to it so that the script writes out all users starting from uid 1000.
I need another function to write info about a specific user, for example: Bash myprogram.sh -ul Erik
and then the script will list username, password, uid, guid, comment, directory and shell of that specific user.
In the program I use $1 for the command and $2 for the second input, which will be the username

Answer (score 4):

One could do this with `getent` and `awk` …

```
getent passwd Erik | awk -F: '{print "Username: " $1 "\nPassword: " $2 "\nUid: " $3 "\nGid: " $4 "\nComment: " $5 "\nHome: " $6 "\nShell: " $7 "\n"}'
```

… but it's time to remember an old command, and that not everything is an exercise in `awk` or `perl`:

```
finger -l -k Erik
```

Some operating systems might not have a `-k` option, note.  (It excludes some information that you have not expressed an interest in.)  But `-l` is fairly universal.

## Further reading

- [read files directly VS getent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/196829/5132)
- [How could I find the Plan command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/481652/5132)
- [What is `plan` for users?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122782/5132)

Comment: I like the getent aproach, as it will catch other user databases (like NIS and LDAP/Active Directory).

Answer (score 1):

Try something around this:

```
awk -F: '{if ($3 >= 1000) {print "Username: " $1 "\nPassword: " $2 "\nUid: " $3 "\nGid: " $4 "\nComment: " $5 "\nHome: " $6 "\nShell: " $7 "\n---"}} /etc/passwd
```

Comment: FWIW the `{if ($3 >= 1000)` can be stripped down to just `$3>=1000 {` and the final `}` removed.